# Reference a static template in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

I want to use angular with symfony2. To do so it should be possible to load a template from a reference like this:

```
<div ng-include="/link/to/template.html"></div>
```

The loading is the part of angular. We just have to provide a path to the template. The template should not be rendered with twig. Is this possible with symfony?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple make a template without twig tags, and a route for it to load via ajax. No controller is required

```
my_template:
    path: /path/to/template
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template: 'AcmeBundle:Angular:template.html.twig'
```

More infos: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html

Comment: In in addition if you ever need twig in future you can use it like in any other template ;)

Comment: if the template is located in the app/resources folder its possible to call it like this : 
                  template : '::template.html.twig'